# How to detect current input-text's index from an array of input-text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I have an array of input text boxes simplified as bellow:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[3]" value="0">
<input type="text" name="quantity[6]" value="0">
<input type="text" name="quantity[7]" value="0">
<input type="text" name="quantity[11]" value="0">
```

Either of the two ways is acceptable for me, but I don't know how to do even one of them:

When the 3rd input box (with has index 7) is changed, either of the two `alert()`s is acceptable for me:

- 7 (because the real index of the 3rd text box is `7`)
- 2 (because probably it will be counted from 0 and thus its index will be 2)

My code that doesn't work is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name^=quantity]').change(function(){
        alert($(this).index());
    });
})
```

Link: **http://niamco.com/cp/problem.html**

It is expected that when the user changes any of the **Quantity** text boxes, the text box's `val()` be alerted as well as their correct `index()`. We see that the `val()` is outputted correctly, but the `index()` is always returned `0`.

As the `val()` is correct, we should be sure that jQuery is loaded well and working. So why shouldn't `index()` be true?

Strange is that as I've researched, both `val()` and `index()` are jQuery functionalities. If `val()` was javascript base, it could be accepted. But now, one jquery Base function works, and the other does not!

Comment: `.index()` gets the position of the element, I think you'll need to use a simple regex to parse the number from the name.

Comment: Your code worked for me to get the true index.

Comment: If 2 is acceptable, then your code is working `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/V44Ty/

Comment: Thank you friends, I will check the fiddle. Mine is not really working. It is returning `0` when it should return `2`.

Comment: What browser are you using to test @smhnaji?

Comment: Yes, the fiddle is working, but I'm interested why it's not working at my situation. @DanielGimenez it's Ubuntu's Google Chromium.

Comment: @smhnaji, do you have a url we can look at?

Comment: Thank you @DanielGimenez. The live link is: http://niamco.com/cp/problem.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.index()` gets the element's current position relative to it's siblings. You should use a regex to get the number between `[` and `]` in the input's name.

Use this instead:

```
$('input[name^=quantity]').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).prop('name').match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
    console.log(index);
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/u8HRq/1/

**UPDATE**: Based on your update here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbmAU/2/

First off `id`s should be unique so I've changed them to classes and updated the selector for the `change` event.

I've also got `.index()` working:

```
$(this).index('.quantity')
```

`index()` usually works by returning the position relative to the matching siblings which is why mine and j08691's answers were working. However, if the elements aren't siblings then you can pass a selector as an argument. This returns the `index` of the current element relative to the matched elements.

Comment: I should thank for your try. I've updated the q with the link http://niamco.com/cp/problem.html. I would also thank if you have time and help me with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This gets both:

```
 $('input[name^=quantity]').change(function () {
     console.log($(this).index(), +$(this).prop('name').match(/\d+/g));
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zeWZu/3/)**

`$(this).index()` is the true index

`+$(this).prop('name').match(/\d+/g)` is the index from the attribute

---

Update: After you updated your question to show the code you're really using, this should help you:

```
$('input[name^=quantity]').change(function () {
    console.log($(this).closest('table').find('input[name^=quantity]').index($(this)), +$(this).prop('name').match(/\d+/g));
});
```

`+$(this).prop('name').match(/\d+/g)` still works to get the index from the attribute

`$(this).closest('table').find('input[name^=quantity]').index($(this))` but you'll need this format using `.index()` to get the index of the input elements since they're not siblings of each other. You need to pass an argument for the collection of elements you want to compare them against, in this case `$(this).closest('table').find('input[name^=quantity]')`.

Comment: Two problems.  You should use prop to get the name property, and /\d/ could mistakenly make `mynamewithadigit1[5]` the result would be 1.

Comment: @DanielGimenez - I'll give you the prop vs attr one, but since this answer is specific to the OP's question and not a generic solution, the /\d/ works (and stands).

Comment: @j0861, but you have to accept those might be generic names just to show for our benefit, but in the actual application he may have an input with a digit in the name.

Comment: @j08691 I should thank for your try. I've updated the q with the link http://niamco.com/cp/problem.html. I would also thank if you have time and help me with the problem.

Comment: Ah, well the issue is that your example code doesn't reflect the actual code where a table is involved. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zeWZu/4/